# Bind destroy link for a newly created item with Ajax in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am implementing comments in Rails 4 application.
I want to create comment and delete comment to work remotely with Ajax.

It works fine except the delete link for a newly added comment doesn't work.

What is the best way of making delete link work for a newly created item?

#### /views/posts/ show.html.haml

```
    .post
        %h1= @post.name

    %h2 Comments
    = render 'comments/form', comment: @comment
    %ul#comments
      = render 'comments/comment', :collection => @post.comments, :as => :comment
```

#### /views/comments/_form.html.haml

```
    .comment-form
      = simple_form_for comment, :remote => true do |f|
        = f.input :body, :input_html => { :rows => "2" }, :label => false
        = f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

#### /views/comments/_comment.html.haml

```
  %li{:"data-id"=>comment.id}
    =comment.body
    %br
    = link_to "Destroy", comment_path(comment), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete, remote: true, :class=>'link_comment_delete'
```

#### /views/comments/destroy.js.rb

```
  $('#comments li[data-id=<%=@comment.id%>]').hide();
```

#### /views/comments/create.js.rb

```
  $("#comments").append("<li><%= escape_javascript render @comment %></li>");

  // ??? what to write here to make Delete link work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same exact situation, and ended up re-thinking the `delete` view  by using `.closest` instead of biding to `data-id`, so you can do something like:

```
$("a.link_comment_delete").on('ajax:complete',function(e) {
    $(this).closest('div.comment.body [or whatever class / id you are using]').fadeOut(100)
    });
```

Comment: thanks! in my case I did "  ** $("ul#comments").on( "ajax:success", "li a.link_comment_delete", function() {
    $(this).closest('li').hide();
  }); **
"

Comment: and destroy.js.erb should be empty